# Pull table rows and add property table rows as additional columns

Tags: mysql

I'm honestly not sure how to ask this question, so I will explain with examples.

Let's say I have a table, `company`, which is set up as:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Nav Corp |
| 2 | Banner LLC |

Then, there is a properties table, which we'll just call `property` set up as:

| id | company_id | tag | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | phone | 555-123-4567 |
| 2 | 2 | city | Nowheresville |
| 3 | 1 | phone | 555-987-6543 |
| 4 | 1 | city | Somewhereelse |

I want to be able to pull results which would be:

| id | name | phone | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nav Corp | 555-987-6543 | Somewhereelse |
| 2 | Banner LLC | 555-123-4567 | Nowheresville |

The `tag` from the `property` table becomes the field label, and the `value` is just the value.

Now, I know I can do this by writing a query and just join the `property` table for each different tag like:

```
Select `company`.*, `phone`.`value`, `city`.`value`
From `company`
Left Join `property` As `phone` On (`company`.`id` = `phone`.`company_id` And `phone`.`tag` = 'Phone')
Left Join `property` As `city` On (`company`.`id` = `city`.`company_id` And `city`.`tag` = 'city')
Group By `company`.`id`;
```

However, I would love the ability to essentially pull each different tag for a company without having to write it all out like this.  If I add a new tag, I would not want to have to go back through queries to add it.

With that being said, I know that I "should" put all the data that I want to pull when pulling a list into the actual company table, and the property table should just be for when only pulling data for one company to display the info, but I'm still wanting to know if this is possible in a simpler query.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: And consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: @Strawberry I appreciate the reply, but this isn't a question of how to display the data, but of how to pull it.  I'm trying to find out if it's possible to pull the main table and automatically pull each tag/value in the property table for each row all in one query.

Comment: I call that a display issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can somehow simplify the query with conditional aggregation:

```
select c.*, 
    max(case when p.tag = 'phone' then value end) as phone,
    max(case when p.tag = 'city'  then value end) as city
from company c
left join property p on p.company_id = p.id
group by c.id
```

However, this does not automagically creates new columns when new tags are added to the property table (it just makes it easier to extend the query, since you just need to modify the `select` clause). If that's what you want, then you need dynamic SQL, which is much more complicated.

Comment: This seems to involve "having to write it all out like this"